# <%= foo %> not pulling value through on css src

Tags: html, css, asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to force a value into the linked .js and .css files. It works fine on my js files but not on my css. Example code:

```
<script src="/Scripts/ExampleJSFile.js?v=<%= version %>"></script>
<link href="/Styles/ExampleCSSFile.css?v=<%= version %>" rel="stylesheet" >
```

Which is giving the following result:

```
<script src="/Scripts/ExampleJSFile.js?v=5.0.0.1"></script>
<link href="Styles/ExampleCSSFile.css?v=<%= version %>" rel="stylesheet">
```

I am using asp.net c# (WebForms) as my code behind framework.

Thanks

Comment: What system (preprocessor/framework) are you using? Please tag it.

Comment: There is no reason that it does not work unless the css has a `runat=server` property.

Comment: When did the leading / get dropped, or is that just a typo in the question?

Answer (score 0):

*Event binding and dynamic codes run only on server side controls and code snippet that can be accessed by .net.*

By default asp.net process script src tag and replace value for you, But when it come to somethings like css link or favicons, the compiler dose not process your code and just send it to client.

You must place things like these into server container elements like placeholder.

I always use code like this to solve it:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="StylesPlaceHolder">
<link href="/Styles/ExampleCSSFile.css?v=<%= version %>" rel="stylesheet" >
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

It will result in something like this:

```
<link href="/Styles/ExampleCSSFile.css?v=5.0.0.1" rel="stylesheet" >
```